# How to replace an old string with new string for first occurence without using any API

Tags: java

I have string like

```
String str = "This is john";
```

In that above string i need replace  "is" with "was"

This is my code

```
class replaces
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 

      {
        String s = "  This is john  ";

        String input = "is";

        String old = "was";

        String s1[] = s.split(" ");

         for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
        {
            if(s1[i]==input)
            {
                s1[i]=old;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s1[i]);
        }
}

}
```

when i execute this its printing the same string -

> This is john

If anybody can explain how to solve this if you have  that code just post it.

Its useful for me.. Thank You

Comment: "without using any api". without using any api, you can't do anything. be more clear.

Comment: anyway, you can't compare the values of (String) objects using the == operator. Your problem lies here:  if(s1[i]==input)

Comment: I used equals() also but i printing the same string "is"  @Stultuske

Comment: @Sridhar If you use `equals()` it works fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0xkkaI).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its Java code, your problem is that in your case, you need to use the equals() method comparison of strings, not the equality sign. Rather use s1[i].equals(input) instead of s1[i]==input

Comment: ya i used equals() but its printing the same string 'is'

Comment: @Sridhar If you use `equals()` it works fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0xkkaI).

Answer (score 0):

s = s.replace(" is ", " was ");

String method

Comment: That changes the string `"  This is john  "` to `"  Thwas was john  "`.

Comment: but you know where i'm heading with it.. use the replace-method, String is offering... in your case with a space before and after "is"/"was"

Comment: Yes i used replace() its a easy way to replace string but i need replace without using API.                                                                                         I faced this kind of question in interview that's only finding a solutions @Andreas

Comment: @Sridhar If `replace()` violates the undefined "without using API", why doesn't `split()` do so as well? `split()` is actually more advanced, given that is uses a regular expression. Since you can't do *anything* without using *some* API, I'd guess that `indexOf()` and `substring()` might be ok.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's solve *with* any reasonable API:

```
String source = "This is john";
String find = "is";
String replace = "was";

int index = source.indexOf(find);

// actually we don't have to change the first occurense (that is in the "thIS"),
// we want "is" to be a separate word i.e. either in the begining/ending of the string 
// or started/followed by spaces
while (index >= 0) 
  if (((index == 0) || 
       (source.charAt(index - 1) == ' ')) &&
      ((index + find.length() >= source.length()) || 
       (source.charAt(index + find.length()) == ' ')))
    break; // this occurence is OK 
  else
    index = source.indexOf(find, index + 1); // next one, please

String result = index >= 0
    ? source.substring(0, index) + replace + source.substring(index + find.length())
    : source;
```

then inspect which API used is allowed. I guess, that `length()`, `charAt()` have to be allowed; 
as for `indexOf()` and `substring()` you can easily implement them.